# wordpress query to show all images by authors

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I recently did a conversion from a really old db to a wordpress compatible one.

It's quite a simple site, that allows Artists to show there artwork.

In the worpdress media library each image has an author/image attached to it.

Is there a wordpress query that allows us to tap into this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `query_posts()`

```
query_posts('author=1&post_type=image');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I forgot to mention that not all the images are attached to posts. Still use this method?

Comment: yes you can still use this method because every image uploaded to wordpress is a "post" for itself.